# How to setup a FTP site with permission to upload, but not download or remove files?

Tags: linux, permissions, ftp, arch-linux

I'm currently trying to set up a FTP site which only allows users to upload files using vsftpd in archlinux. After some googling I didn't find any satisfactory solutions.

The current partial solution is as follows. In vsftpd.conf, I set download_enabled to FALSE and write_enable to TRUE. I created a user in linux that is only used for this ftp site.

Specifically, my problem is:

Are there any ways to differentiate between permission for uploading files and permission for  deleting files, and accordingly, enabling one while disabling the other?

The relevant softwares, vsftpd and archlinux, are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

wu-ftpd has an [ftpaccess](http://wu-ftpd.therockgarden.ca/man/ftpaccess.html) configuration file which has a `noretrieve` option.

```
  noretrieve [absolute|relative] [class=<classname>] ... [-]
     <filename> <filename> ...

        Always deny retrieve-ability of these files.  If  the
        files  are a path specification (i.e. begins with '/'
        character) then only those files are  marked  un-get­
        table, otherwise all files with matching the filename
        are refused transfer.  For example:
            noretrieve /etc/passwd core
        specifies no  one  will  be  able  to  get  the  file
        /etc/passwd  whereas they will be allowed to transfer
        a file `passwd' if it is not in /etc.  On  the  other
        hand  no  one  will be able to get files named `core'
        wherever they are.
```

It also has a rich set of options for setiing up restricted-access drop-off type FTP services isolated from the rest of the filesystem (a bit like chrooted FTP).

You may be able to install wu-ftpd and run it in place of your standard FTP daemon.